# How to split a file into words keeping punctuation, in bash?

Tags: bash, split

For example, I have a file with normal text, like:

```
"Word1 word2, word3; word4. Word5"
```

I want to get a file with 1 word per line, keeping the punctiuation, and ordered:

```
,
.
;
Word1
word2
word3
word4
Word5
```

Googling so far, I found this closest to what I need:

```
#!/bin/sh


for word in $(cat "input_file.txt"):
        do echo $word >> output_file1.txt;

done


sort "output_file1.txt" >> "output_file2.txt"
```

This produces the output of this kind:

```
Word1
word2, 
word3;
word4.
Word5
```

obviously delimiting by white space. 
How can I delimit by white space and punctuation characters, keeping them?

P.S: file input file is rich in special characters, e.g. diacretical marks:

Kuͦn, zuͦ, buͤtten, güetter.

When applying `grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' file` they are split as if the diacretical mark was a delimiter:

```
gu
̈
etter
```

Though in other cases these characters don't affect the splitting:

```
brüchen
```

Comment: Two questions: **(1.)** when you say **'and ordered'** do you mean keeping the punctuation in the order they were encountered? **(2.)** what are the **possible punctuation characters** used? Is that it `. ,;`?

Comment: Ordered - in alphabetical order. Possible punctuation characters: `. , () : ;`

Comment: Got it, if there is no need to preserve `Word/punct` association, the answer already given will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grep -Eo`:

```
grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' file
Word1
word2
,
word3
;
word4
.
Word5
```

To sort it:

```
grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' file | sort -f
,
.
;
Word1
word2
word3
word4
Word5
```

**PS:** You can also use `grep` without `-E`:

```
grep -o '[[:alnum:]]\+\|[[:punct:]]'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! But when a character is a letter with diacritical marks, sometimes it puts letter on one line, and the marks on the following, e.g. Kuͦn -> K  u 
ͦ
  n

Comment: Ah but I didn't know there were non-ASCII letters also in your file. If that is the case then I guess you will need to provide more examples.

Comment: You may need to open a new question for dealing with non-ASCII characters. I would think: `grep -Po '[\p{L}\d]+|[^\d\p{L} ]' file` would work with right LOCALE etc.

Comment: I've verified that above `grep` works with proper `UTF-8` encoded data. You just need to make sure your input is using `UTF-8`

Comment: I checked my input file's encoding with 'file --mime' command, it says that this is a UTF8 file: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'

Comment: When I copy paste your text in a UTF-8 page it becomes `Kuͦn, zuͦ, buͤtten, güetter` which is not what you have posted.

Comment: So, to avoid my problem, I need to copy my text to a UTF8 page? What does a UTF8 page mean?

Comment: Basically in whatever editor you're entering text make sure to save it in UTF-8 encoding. You can read online manuals for your editor on using UTF-8

Comment: Thank you :) I almost managed to handle the problem by replacing "bad" ü ö ä by those I copied from the utf8 character table. As for such characters as uͦ and uͤ, they are neither in utf8 nor in ascii tables, so I guess I cannot replace them with anything compatible. I will create a new question about it.

Comment: Yes do create a new question and SO experts will try their best to assist you.